# Looping through rows in bash to implement a condition that checks if values are the same

Tags: bash

I have a table like this

```
1,879468,944088,A,C,K,Q,0.159,ENST00000342066
1,879468,944088,A,G,K,E,0.160,ENST00000342066
1,879469,944089,A,C,K,T,0.185,ENST00000342066
1,879469,944089,A,C,Q,T,0.185,ENST00000342066
```

I want to check the following condition. When column 1, column 2, column 3, and column 4  are the same across rows for example

```
1,879468,944088,A,
1,879468,944088,A
```

Column 6 must be the same too for example

```
1,879468,944088,A,C,K,Q,0.159,ENST00000342066
1,879468,944088,A,G,K,E,0.160,ENST00000342066
```

in these two rows is ok because K is the same. However, I have seen a few lines in which this condition is not true so I am developing a script that shows me these lines. I am trying this

```
awk -F ',' '{
   key = $1","$2","$3","$4;
   if (key in arr) {
       if ($6 != arr[key]) {
           print "Mismatch found at", key, ":", $6, "!=", arr[key];
       }
   } else {
       arr[key] = $6;
   }
}' my_table.txt
```

but I do not get any results or an error.

For the reproducible data given at the beginning, the result should be the last line because Q should be a K. I need to identify lines like this

Comment: For which line in the input data you posted, would you expect a mismatch?

Comment: Shouldn't you initialize `arr` to an empty array before checking it?

Comment: The last line (1,879469,944089,A,C,Q,T,0.185,ENST00000342066), that Q should be a K.

Comment: @ManoloDominguezBecerra Your code works with your sample; I get `Mismatch found at 1,879469,944089,A : Q != K`

Comment: Tested here with GNU `awk` and the `awk` that comes with macOS: `Mismatch found at 1,879469,944089,A : Q != K`. What `awk` do you use?

Comment: Sorry, I closed the terminal and opened again and my code worked. I have spent 3 hours on this! :( Thank you all for you help

Comment: Closed? It's definitely a programming question, while the problem wasn't a bug in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, does it matter which value is right or wrong Q or K? Coz if Q will be the first in file your code will output 3 times that K is mismatch. Try instead sorting out them all like this for example:

```
# test file
$ cat f
1 2 3 4 51 60 71 85 99 108
1 2 3 4 52 60 72 84 98 170
1 2 3 4 53 61 73 83 97 108
1 2 3 4 54 60 74 82 96 105

awk '{
       arr[$1","$2","$3","$4"_"$6]["total"]++
       arr[$1","$2","$3","$4"_"$6]["line"]=NR
     }
     END{for(i in arr)print i, arr[i]["total"], arr[i]["line"]}
' f
```

output:

```
1,2,3,4_60 3 4
1,2,3,4_61 1 3
```

Here we can see that there are 3 lines with 60 and only 1 with 61(at line 3).